# how to create a normal user in Bitbucket data server?

Tags: bitbucket-server

I setup a Bitbucket data server on the cloud VM. Everyhing works great except of the user management. I found all users that are created in Bitbucket server default to SYS.ADMIN. I read the official doc of Bitbucket. Have not found out a way to create a user with only limited permission in Bitbucket.

How can I do this?

Comment: not sure why the default setting for user is sysadmin. But I can address this by changing the user permission settings to remove the sysadmin